# Navigation Drawer Item added programmatically not getting HIGHLIGHTED when checked

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I have created a navigation drawer.

XML for Menu is as under **main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu ...
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_table_chart_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_topic_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_plan"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_table_chart_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_plan" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The navigation view is added in XML as under - **main_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    ... >

<FrameLayout ...> </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/main_drawer"/>
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Other than the two menu items, Home and Plan than you see in the XML, few menu items are added programmatically in the navigation menu using the below code

```
mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
Menu navigationMenu = mNavigationView.getMenu();                
for(int inx = 0; inx < myMenuItems.size() ; inx ++) {
    navigationMenu
       .add(0, inx, 0, myMenuItems.get(inx))
       .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_table_chart_black_24dp)
       .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}
```

In the listener, which is the main activity, the code is as under:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
     
     // Fragment setting code here

     item.setChecked(true);
     mNavigationView.setCheckedItem(item.getItemId());
}
```

With this code, the menu appears and looks as below (Notice that currently **Home** is checked and is highlighted [important])

[image]

Now, when I select another menu item (the **one that is added programmatically**, then it is getting checked, but **not getting highlighted**)

[image]

**Any clue ?**

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that the [`MenuItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem) object [`isCheckable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem#isCheckable()). Like so:

```java
MenuItem item = navigationMenu
       .add(0, inx, 0, myMenuItems.get(inx))
item.isCheckable = true
...
```

Comment: I got the answer by this time. But since you correctly pointed first, you get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you have a group of checkable menu items and you want to add the new items to it. So, first of all, you should assign an unique id to the group so that you could be able to find it to add the new items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu ...
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:id="@+id/group1"  // <--- assigning an id
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_table_chart_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_topic_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_plan"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_table_chart_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_plan" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Then, when you want to add a new menu item, pass the group id to the `add` method and also enable its checkability:

```java
navigationMenu
    .add(R.id.group1, inx, Menu.NONE, myMenuItems.get(inx))  // <--- pass the group's id
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_table_chart_black_24dp)
    .setCheckable(true)                               // <--- enable item's checkability
    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
```